# How to see json from RestRequest object?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have RestRequest that I format to Json and add and send toSerialize which works just fine. I just want to retrieve the generated json from restRequest object. How can I accomplish that? I searched inside the class and I found no way to see the body.

thanks

```
[DataContract]
public class ToSerialize
{
    [DataMember]
    public string somefield { get; set; }
}



        var request = new RestRequest("/someresource", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        var toSerialize = new ToSerialize();
        toSerialize.someField = "hey";
        request.AddBody(toSerialize);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking on the wrong object.

The body comes back on the response object under the property Content.

Link to the interface:
https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IRestResponse.cs#L38